# Java regex pattern matching (Irish car registration)

Tags: java, regex

Sorry if this a dumb question but it's been driving me mental for the past 5 days.

I'm trying to make a **regex pattern** to match the **Irish** car registration example '`12-W-1234`'
So far this is what I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ValidateDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        input.add("12-WW-1");
        input.add("12-W-223");
        input.add("02-WX-431");
        input.add("98-zd-4134");
        input.add("99-c-7465");


        for (String car : input) {
            if (car.matches("^(\\d{2}-?\\w*([KK|kk|ww|WW|c|C|ce|CE|cn|CN|cw|CW|d|D|dl|DL|g|G|ke|KE|ky|KY|l|L|ld|LD|lh|LH|lk|LK|lm|LM|ls|LS|mh|MH|mn|MN|mo|MO|oy|OY|so|SO|rn|RN|tn|TN|ts|TS|w|W|wd|WD|wh|WH|wx|WX])-?\\d{1,4})$")) {
                System.out.println("Car Template " + car);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problems are coming up when it is checking regs that would have a **single letter** in the that is in my pattern. Eg `'12-ZD-1234'`.
Where `ZD` isn't a valid county ID but since `D` is valid it allows it to be displayed.

Any help would be great.

I've already done research on a few websites including [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/java-regular-expression-tutorial-with-examples.html) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

These websites helped, but I'm still having my problems.

By the by, I'am going to change the pattern to change all inputs into
uppercase to reduce the size of my code.
Thanks for the help

Comment: why do you have the \\w* part before the list of valid country codes?

Comment: Yeah, the \\w* is what is causing the problem. If you already have a complete list of county codes, just use them. No need to glob anything.

Comment: If i dont use the \\w* it will only take single values example "12-WW-1" will be invalid but "12-W-1" will be valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides the `\\w*` that others have pointed out, you're misusing *character classes* (`[...]`). To actually use *alternation* (`|`), take out the square brackets as well:

```
^(\\d{2}-?(KK|kk|ww|WW|c|C|ce|CE|cn|CN|cw|CW|d|D|dl|DL|g|G|ke|KE|ky|KY|l|L|ld|LD|lh|LH|lk|LK|lm|LM|ls|LS|mh|MH|mn|MN|mo|MO|oy|OY|so|SO|rn|RN|tn|TN|ts|TS|w|W|wd|WD|wh|WH|wx|WX)-?\\d{1,4})$
```

Here are some examples to show you how *character classes* actually work:

1. `[abc]` matches a *single* character, either `a`, `b`, or `c`.
2. `[aabbcc]` is equivalent to `[abc]` (duplicates are disregarded).
3. `[|]` matches a pipe character, *i.e.* symbols are allowed.
4. `[KK|kk|ww|WW|c|C|ce|CE ... ]` ends up being equivalent to `[K|wWcCeE ... ]` because, again, duplicates are disregarded.

You were correct to use the *alternation* operator (`|`) to do what you desired, but you didn't need to use character classes.

Comment: @Reimeus - Thanks, Reimeus. Perhaps he does need his anchors. I don't know his context fully so I changed only what seemed wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve you pattern like this:

```
^[0-9]{2}-?(?>c[enw]?|C[ENW]?|dl?|DL?|g|G|k[eky]|K[EKY]|l[dhkms]?|L[DHKMS]?|m[hno]|M[HNO]|oy|OY|rn|RN|so|SO|t[ns]|T[NS]|w[dhx]?|W[DHX]?)-?[0-9]{1,4}$
```

And if you don't care about the case of letters:

```
^(?i)[0-9]{2}-?(?>c[enw]?|dl?|g|k[eky]|l[dhkms]?|m[hno]oy|rn|so|t[ns]|w[dhx]?)-?[0-9]{1,4}$
```

Note that anchors (`^` and `$`) are useful if your string must only contain the car registration number.

Note2: You can improve it more, if you put at the first place in the alternation the most frequent county.

Answer (score 0):

Irish numberplates can also start with three digits, since 2013, they are now (year)(1|2)-(county)-(number), so the regex could be simply (\d+-?\w{2}-?\d+)

[image]

However, the best form of validataion is to run this against a vehicle registraion API, such as http://ie.carregistrationapi.com/ - since this will determine if the vehicle is registered, rather than just being in the right format.